# La posicion del Elemento del List Cambia con SearchView y tengo una vista no esperada

Tags: android, lista, searchview

Buen Dia!!!
El resultado de Searchview está bien, pero cuando hago clic en el Recycler para iniciar otra actividad sobre con los datos del producto este cambia. Ejemplo: cuando busco un producto ejemplo "Aceite", muestra el resultado de "Cerveza", porque la posicion del aceite paso a ser 0 por lo tanto al hacerle clic me trae la cerveza que en la lista general (no filtrada) es la posicion cero. Asi con todo los productos que son filtrado.

creeria que el problema esta en el clic del producto pero no logro darme cuenta:
esta clase es mi Adapter:

```
public class ArticulosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticulosAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<ArticulosBean> listArticulos;


//Constructor
public ArticulosAdapter(List<ArticulosBean> listArticulos, Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.listArticulos = listArticulos;
}



//Cargo el cardview con inflate
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.articulos_card, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder customViewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(itemView, mContext,listArticulos);

    return customViewHolder;
}

/**
 *  Populate the views with appropriate Text and Images
 * @param holder
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ArticulosAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ArticulosBean articulos = listArticulos.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(articulos.getName());
    holder.price.setText("$" +String.valueOf(articulos.getPrice()));
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(articulos.getImageResource())
            .error(R.drawable.item_ejemplo)
            .into(holder.image);
    holder.stock.setText("Disponibles: " +articulos.getStock());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listArticulos.size();
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, price, stock;
    public ImageView image;
    public List<ArticulosBean> articulos;
    Context mctx;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView, final Context mctx, final List<ArticulosBean> articulos) {
        super(itemView);
        this.articulos = articulos;
        this.mctx = mctx;
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizzaName);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizzaPrice);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizzaImage);
        stock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizzaStock);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();// ACA TENGO LA POSICION DEL ARTIC.
                ArticulosBean art = articulos.get(position);

                String dato = String.valueOf(position);
                Toast.makeText(mctx, dato.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mctx, Detalle_articulos.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre_art", art.getName().toString());
                intent.putExtra("precio_art", String.valueOf(art.getPrice()));
                intent.putExtra("imagen_art", String.valueOf(art.getImageResource()));
                intent.putExtra("stock_art", String.valueOf(art.getStock()));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mctx.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
}

//METODO UTILIZADO PARA BUSCAR CON SEARCHVIEW
public void setfilter(List<ArticulosBean> lista)
{
    listArticulos=new ArrayList<>();
    listArticulos.addAll(lista);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Alguna sugerencia??? desde ya muy agradecido por tomarse el tiempo de leer

Comment: Hola, te podria decir que revises este ejemplo que me ayudo mucho, ya que creo que te faltan algunas cosas, deberias extender la clase a Filterable. https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno mi problema se soluciono con solo movimiento

cambie:

```
  ArticulosBean art = articulos.get(position);
```

por:

```
  ArticulosBean art = listArticulos.get(position);
```

esto funciono excelente!!!!